# run one ansible task only once during starting and run one ansible task at end

Tags: linux, ansible

I have below ansible playbook in which I want to do few things:

- I want to run first task only once in entire time this playbook will be running since I have 100 machines in `servers` group so "task one" should run only once in the starting.
- I want to run task three once as well but at the very end of this playbook when it is working on last machine. I am not sure if this is possible to do as well.

What I need to do is:

- Copy `clients.tar.gz` file from some remote servers to local box (inside /tmp folder) where my ansible is running.
- And then unarchive this "clients.tar.gz" file on all the servers specified in "servers" group.
- And at the end delete this tar.gz file from /tmp folder.

Below is my ansible script: Is this possible to do by any chance?

```
---
- name: copy files
  hosts: servers
  serial: 10
  tasks:
      - name: copy clients.tar.gz file. Run this task only once during starting
        shell: "(scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no goldy@machineA:/process/snap/20180418/clients.tar.gz /tmp/) || (scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no goldy@machineB:/process/snap/20180418/clients.tar.gz /tmp/) || (scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no goldy@machineC:/process/snap/20180418/clients.tar.gz /tmp/)"

      - name: copy and untar latest clients.tar.gz file
        unarchive: src=/tmp/clients.tar.gz dest=/data/files/

      - name: Remove previous tarFile. Run this task only once at the end of this playbook
        file: path=/tmp/clients.tar.gz
              state=absent

      - name: sleep for few seconds
        pause: seconds=20
```

**Update**

I went through the linked question and it looks like it can be done like this?

```
---
- name: copy files
  hosts: servers
  serial: 10
  tasks:
      - name: copy clients.tar.gz file. Run this task only once during starting
        shell: "(scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no goldy@machineA:/process/snap/20180418/clients.tar.gz /tmp/) || (scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no goldy@machineB:/process/snap/20180418/clients.tar.gz /tmp/) || (scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no goldy@machineC:/process/snap/20180418/clients.tar.gz /tmp/)"
        delegate_to: "{{ groups['servers'] | first }}"
        run_once: true

      - name: copy and untar latest clients.tar.gz file
        unarchive: src=/tmp/clients.tar.gz dest=/data/files/

      - name: Remove previous tarFile. Run this task only once at the end of this playbook
        file: path=/tmp/clients.tar.gz
              state=absent
        delegate_to: "{{ groups['servers'] | last }}"
        run_once: true

      - name: sleep for few seconds
        pause: seconds=20
```

Comment: @techraf I looked into that question and I updated my ansible in the question. Wanted to see if thats the way we will do it. I update task one and three both. Also on what order of hosts ansible will work on? Is it from top to bottom or bottom to top?